PHP - How can I loop through an array to compare consecutive values including first and last values
The following array contains a list of coordinates that I'm using to draw a polygon with ImageMagick:
$points = [
    ['x' => 40, 'y' => 10],
    ['x' => 20, 'y' => 20],
    ['x' => 70, 'y' => 50],
    ['x' => 60, 'y' => 15],
];

What I want to do is loop through this array and calculate the mid-point of each line segment by comparing each consecutive pair of coordinates including the first and last set i.e. the check must wrap-around either at the start or end of the loop. Is there a way to do this programatically without a lot of kludgey code to count the number of elements in the array and if() tests to determine when the first or last element has been reached, etc.?

You can loop from 0 to count($points)-1, then handle the last element separately outside the loop.

Use modulus to wrap around to 0 at the end.
$midpoints = [];
$len = count($points);
foreach ($points as $i => $point1) {
    $point2 = $points[($i+1) % $len];
    $midpoints[] = get_midpoint($point1, $point2);
}


Thank you, this is what I wanted. In my get_midpoint() function I added $midpoint_x = abs(($point1['x'] - $point2['x']) / 2); $midpoint_y = abs(($point1['y'] - $point2['y']) / 2); return [$midpoint_x, $midpoint_y]; and this returns the expected results.

Is this what you're after? Updated
$points = [
    ['x' => 40, 'y' => 10],
    ['x' => 20, 'y' => 20],
    ['x' => 70, 'y' => 50],
    ['x' => 60, 'y' => 15],
];

$mids = [];

foreach (array_values($points) as $k => $v) {
    if (!empty($points[$k+1])) {
        $x1 = $points[$k]['x'];
        $x2 = $points[$k+1]['x'];
        $y1 = $points[$k]['y'];
        $y2 = $points[$k+1]['y'];
        $mids[] = ['x' => ($x1 + $x2) / 2, 'y' => ($y1 + $y2) / 2];
    }
}

print_r($mids);

output of this is
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [x] => 30
            [y] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [x] => 45
            [y] => 35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [x] => 65
            [y] => 32.5
        )

)


Why use array_values() for an array that's already indexed?

Where is the wraparound at the end?

Thank you, that's nearly there but I also need the mid-point between the first and last elements, because those elements draw the fourth line. This is what I meant by the array needing to have a "wrap-around" aspect to it to do that calculation.

@Barmar presumably $points as declared here is an example for the purposes of asking a SO question but could in reality be coming from a database etc, use of array_values mitigates some issues that could occur, e.g. due to gaps in the array index

Anything is possible, but I can't think of a reason why an array representing the points of a polyline would have non-consecutive indexes. A database query wouldn't normally return anything like that -- they usually return ordinary arrays where the elements are associative, just like the sample.
